# Валидация имени загружаемого файла

Tags: javascript, html

Собственно при загрузке файла, хочу проверять его название и запрещать загрузку, при недопустимых символах.

```
<input type="file" name="filenames" required pattern="[a-z][1-15][A-Z]" ><br>
```

Пытался таким образом, но насколько понимаю это работает только для поля типа text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/857662/3129992

Comment: `[1-15]` - чего???

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам необходимо получить доступ к имени файла, то нужно использовать свойство files элемента [input[type=file]](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/file), которое имеет тип [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileList) и содержит экземпляры [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File):

```js
document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', function(e){
  for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    console.log(this.files[i]);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" multiple />
```

**P.S.** Но почему бы не фильтровать это всё на стороне сервера?

---

#### Ссылке по теме

- [Input[type=file]](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/file)
- [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileList)
- [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)